# database, separate table or columns for extra fields?

Tags: database, database-design

I have `Stock` table.

```
sku
quantity
quantity_sold
price
seller
```

I have `StockExtra` table for products that has date/time property (you can think of event tickets)

```
stock  # references stock
quantity
quantity_sold
price
date_at
time_at
datetime_rule  # foreign key to another table, it is a rule that describes when events occur
```

For event tickets, I use `stock and seller` from the Stock table, but use quantity from StockExtra table. Because a ticket at different date can have different quantity and price.

I've divided the tables but not so sure if it is the best practice.

Now I need to create another table to hold stock data for separate market stores.
(I'm making a system where seller can manage his inventory when he sells products over multiple stores)

One could sell event tickets in amazon.com and in ebay.com for instance. 
And the price, quantity in each store might be different.

So there will be one to many relations from `Stock` to `StoreStock`.

`Stock` will hold default price and aggregated quantity/quantity_sold for all stores.  `StoreStock` will hold data for an individual store.

And I'll also need one to many relations from `StockExtra` to `StoreStock` due to the same reason, i.e price/quantity might be different for each date/time for event tickets.

So with my current setup,
there will be `Stock` `StockExtra` and `StoreStock`.

Would it be better to have just `Stock` and `StoreStock` even though date/time related fields will be empty for non-ticket products?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added the stock field to the StockExtra. (my mistake) "You might be overcomplicating things." please be more specific, are you implying I should just merge the Stock / StockExtra tables?

Answer (score 0):

You should think about reducing the complexity of your system by keeping everything in a consistent way.  Keep complex scenarios in the same tables as simple scenarios.

By keeping the same information in different places (e.g. `Stock` vs `StockExtra`, or `Stock` vs `StoreStock`) you are creating a situation in which your code has to have extra branching to find the data depending on the situation.

When you're going after the data for a single transaction, branching isn't the end of the world, although it is more code to have to write, debug and maintain.  However, when you go after data **in aggregate**, having it spread across multiple potential locations makes your data retrieval *much* more complicated.

I would recommend keeping everything at the most detailed level.  Therefore everything goes in `StoreStock` even if there is only one store applicable to a particular situation.  Then, unless you have a demonstrable performance issue, don't split off `StockExtra` from `Stock` - Just use nullable columns in `Stock`.

It's OK to keep default prices in `Stock`, but use a more descriptive name for the sake of the next guy that has to maintain your code.  I'd advise against tracking sales quantity in the `Stock` table.  Keep this in `StoreStock` only.  Don't keep a pre-calculated quantity on hand value.  This will inevitably be out of whack.  Instead, track quantities added (receipts) and quantities removed (sales) and calculate quantity on hand dynamically.  This will avoid inventory reconciliation problems.